# Splitting N persons into teams of 2

Tags: python, function, indexoutofrangeexception

I have made the following piece of code to split N persons into random teams of 2, but in many cases, I get the error: `pop index out of range`.

Could someone help me?

```
from random import seed
from random import randrange
from datetime import datetime
seed(datetime.now())

N = int(input("How many students do you have?:"))

pupils = set()

for number in range(N):
    pupils.add(str(input('pupil name:')))
print(pupils)


teams = set()
lista = list(pupils)
for i in range(N//2):#// akerea dieresi
    pos1 = randrange(0, len(lista))
    pos2 = randrange(0, len(lista))
    pupil1 = lista.pop(pos1)
    pupil2 = lista.pop(pos2)
    team = (pupil1,pupil2)
    teams.add(team)

i = 0
for team in teams:
    i+=1
    print(team + str(i))
```

Comment: I presume both that `pos1` and `pos2` could be the index of the end of the list sometimes.

Comment: The length of the list changes when you pop `pupil1`, what if `pos2` was `len(lista)-1`?

Comment: You should do a random shuffle of the whole list and then split off [pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

edit:
this error means to say that you are trying to `pop()` from an index that is not on the list.
maybe try to check if the list is already empty each time you try to take something out. I`ll use `if lista` to verify it is not empty.

```
teams = set()
lista = list(pupils)
for i in range(N//2):  #notice yo only have to do that N//2 times!
    if lista:                       #check if lista is empty
        pos1 = randrange(0, len(lista))
        pupil1 = lista.pop(pos1)
    if lista:
        pos2 = randrange(0, len(lista))
        pupil2 = lista.pop(pos2)

    team = (pupil1,pupil2)
    teams.add(team)

i = 0
for team in teams:
    i+=1
    print(team + str(i))
```

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that the list is empty, but that there is no item in it at the index you're trying to `pop`. The OP's code as provided won't let the list get empty anyway. So, testing if the list isn't empty is useless. Furthermore, you are choosing a value in the list, and try to use it as an index in pop, which will cause an error. Please don't post wrong, untested code as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is you are shortening a `list`, but acting like removed indexes should still exist. Your bigger problem is that you are trying to invent your own `random.shuffle()`. Your code could be simplified greatly by using the builtin `random.shuffle()`.

```
import random

#represents the results of your name input system
names = 'Tom Jerry Abbot Costello Regis Kelly Harry Sally Thelma Louise Solomon'.split()

#shuffle all the names
random.shuffle(names)

teams = []

#keep going as long as there are pairs
while len(names) > 1:
    teams.append({names.pop(), names.pop()})

#odd man out
if names:
    print(f"{names.pop()} can't play")

#results
print(*teams, sep='\n')
```